# Where are the docs for older Django versions?

Tags: django

As of this year Django core devs removed docs for Django versions older than 1.7 from https://docs.djangoproject.com/.

Unfortunately, there’re still apps using older Django versions in the wild, such as the project I’m currently busy upgrading.

Googling variations of “django 1.5 docs” gives links to unfamiliar domains such as django-doc-test1.readthedocs.io and django-document-tchinese.readthedocs.io, and a PDF under media.readthedocs.org.

**I’m looking for hosted navigable Django 1.5–1.6 documentation, preferably in HTML, is that still a thing? Any options apart from building the docs myself from source?**

Comment: _"such as the project I'm busy upgrading"_ - having dones this myself (from 1.3), you have my sympathies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs for Django 1.4, 1.5 and 1.6 were removed from the official docs.djangoproject.com site in February 2016. See [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-developers/5TsL3MED5W8/YBtNry6hAwAJ) on the django-developers website for more details.

You can still view the docs for Django 1.4 and later on [readthedocs](https://readthedocs.org/projects/django/).

For earlier versions of Django, you can view the source files on GitHub (for example, [Django 1.3](https://github.com/django/django/tree/stable/1.3.x/docs)), but if you need html versions, you'll have to try building them yourself.